# Core Data NSFetchedResultController not updating on object change?

Tags: core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a NSFetchedResultController with this predicate set:

```
NSPredicate* pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"author != %@ && deleted != %@", [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:0],[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
```

It filters fine on startup, and I get a delegate callback and list updates fine if objects are added or deleted.

But if I change the "deleted" field, the NSFetchedResultController set is NOT updated, nor do I get the callback.

Though, the actual object in the NSFetchedResultController is updated, if I do a "reloadData" on my table and check the value of "deleted", it is actually set to YES.

Why is it not disappearing from the NSFetchedResultController?

Is this expected behavior?
Or what could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I solved it...

Turns out I actually do get the callback ("didChangeObject") and I now check the value of "deleted" here and manually remove it from the NSFetchedResultController if the value is YES.

Seems to work, but I still did expect it to be automatic.